# Invalid syntax showing up in pylint

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, syntax-error, pylint, opencsv

This python code showing this invalid syntax (, line 16) pylint(syntax-error)[15,10] here error showing at semicolon(:)

```
for record in colleges:
    obj.writerow([record['collegeId'], record['collegeName'], record['courseType'], record['city'], record['fees'], record['pinCode']])
```

Comment: Please provide us a minimum reproducible example so we can help you.

Comment: The `for` loop's syntax is wrong. Add a semicolon at the end.

Comment: You might have an error like unbalanced parentheses in the previous line.

Comment: so the problem is resolved now, you should accept the answer. Why did you actually edit the question? it makes no sense now...

Comment: thanks @Matthias problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming obj is a [csv.Writer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects). Even still, you only seem to be missing a colon?

```
for record in colleges:
    obj.writerow([
        record['collegeId'],
        record['collegeName'],
        record['courseType'],
        record['city'],
        record['fees'],
        record['pinCode']
    ])
```

Comment: yes here obj is csv.writer but still showing same error after add colon

Comment: @sowmyapanjala, is this a runtime syntax error or only a message from pylint?